# Can't bind Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Down

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gui

I'm using a GUI program ([Wing IDE](https://wingware.com/)) on Ubuntu where I bind lots of shortcut keys to actions in the program. For some reason, I can't bind `Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Down` and `Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Up`. I can't bind `Ctrl-Alt-Down` and `Ctrl-Alt-Up` either.

I'm guessing that some system shortcut is capturing these key combinations; however, I went over each of the few dozen keyboard shortcuts defined in the Ubuntu Settings, and there are no clashes.

**How can I tell why these shortcuts aren't available? How can I make them available?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to find out which shortcut keys are bound for what. These assignments are all over the place in various `dconf` settings. One trick that may help is to list all dconf settings and grep for the keyboard combination you are looking for, e.g.

```
gsettings list-recursively  | grep 'Down'
```

will list all settings where `Down` is involved.

You will see in that output that that key is assigned to `move-to-workspace-down`. This makes no sense anymore since Ubuntu changed to horizontal workspaces. You can clear this assignment with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "[]"
```

so it becomes available for other uses. You can also use the tool `dconf-editor` to change this using a graphical UI.